# Swiftmailer Attachment Cannot Be Opened (Laravel 3)

Tags: file-upload, email-attachments, swiftmailer, laravel-3

I'm using the Swiftmailer bundle for Laravel 3 and trying to attach an uploaded file to an email message:

```
$message = \Message::bcc(preg_split('/,/', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $to)))
    ->from(Input::get('from'))
    ->subject(Input::get('subject')
    ->body(Input::get('message'));

$attachment_path = null;

if (Input::has_file('attachment')) {
    $filename = Input::file('attachment.name')
    $attachment_path = path('storage') . "files/attachments/";
    if (Input::upload('attachment', $attachment_path, $filename)) {
        $attachment_path = $attachment_path . $filename;
        $attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attachment_path);
        $message->attach($attachment, $filename, Input::file('attachment.type'));
    }
}

$message->send();

// clear up attachments
if ($attachment_path) {
    File::delete($attachment_path);
}
```

I've checked that the file is uploaded correctly and I can open the file on disk. However, when I receive the email and try to open the attachment the file is corrupt and won't open. It has data but the file size is larger than the original.

Answer (score 0):

My bad: `$message->attach()` generates a Swift_Attachment attachment, it does not accept one as a parameter. This is the correction:

<strike>`$attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attachment_path);`</strike>

`$message->attach($attachment_path, $filename, Input::file('attachment.type'));`